# Extend Vaadin widget

Tags: java, widget, vaadin

I am trying to extend tree component in Vaadin. So I created client side class as:

```
import com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.client.ui.VTree;
public class CustomVtree extends VTree {
}
```

Server side class :

```
import com.vaadin.ui.ClientWidget;
import com.vaadin.ui.Tree;
@ClientWidget(CustomVtree.class)
public class MyTree extends Tree {
    public MyTree() {
        super();
    }
}
```

And I got 
`[WARN] Widget class com.vaadin.sample.gwt.client.ui.CustomVtree was not found. The component com.vaadin.sample.gwt.client.ui.MyTree will not be included in the widgetset.`
What did I forget to do or what I am doing wrong? Will be glad for any help. Thanks

Comment: The Сonnector does not need to be created?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your classes look correct but one thing is missing: a GWT module descriptor file. Add that file to the com.vaadin.sample.gwt package and here I call it MyWidgetset.gwt.xml. The content of the file should look like the following if you don't have any add-ons in your project:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE module PUBLIC "-//Google Inc.//DTD Google Web Toolkit 1.7.0//EN" "http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.7.0/distro-source/core/src/gwt-module.dtd">
<module>
    <inherits name="com.vaadin.terminal.gwt.DefaultWidgetSet" />
</module>
```

And then you have to define in web.xml that you want to use this widgetset:

```
<init-param>
    <description>Application widgetset</description>
    <param-name>widgetset</param-name>
    <param-value>com.vaadin.sample.gwt.MyWidgetset</param-value>
</init-param>
```

After these steps the GWT compilation should work.

Answer (score 1):

What is the package declaration ?

When extending client-side component, the client-side class should in

yourpackage.widgetset.client.ui

When compiling, this package is scan to found any widget and add it to your widgetset.

Then you have to modify your web.xml to change the init-param tag.

Here a bref resume to help you : [Creating a widget](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/gwt.eclipse.html#gwt.eclipse.widget)